Upgrading from .NET Framework 4.7 to .NET 8 causes the designer won't load
I have a personal project for school written in VB.NET. Before this, the framework I was using was .NET Framework 4.7. Then, I decided to upgrade it to .NET 8 because I need DPI awareness feature in it. But now I can't open any Form Designer with this error.
Type 'System.IO.MemoryStream' in Assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' is not marked as serializable. 

here's the call stack:

at StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d_154'1.MoveNext(
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerHost.d_16.MoveNext(
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d_29.MoveNext(
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader .< >c_DisplayClass25_1 .<<- ctor>b_1>d.MoveNext(
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw0
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d_27.MoveNext(


I've been doing some research before this. One workaround that I tried was moving all the project files (form, resources, etc.) from old solution to the new solution. It worked If I only moved some of the forms (the designer will load). But, when I moved all the forms, the same error pops up again. I clearly had no idea with this issue.
Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you!

Not clear what you have done to upgrade your Solution. See Upgrade a .NET Framework Windows Forms desktop app to .NET 8 -- BTW, .NET Framework (better if it's 4.8 / 4.8.1) also supports DpiAwareness (up to PerMonitorV2). .NET defaults to SystemAware, which should also be changed to PerMonitorV2 in the projects' configuration files

See also the general info about the Upgrade Assistant: Bring your apps to the latest .NET

.NET 8 is .NET Core 8, a completely different platform. You can't just change the version number. How did you upgrade the project? Did the Upgrade Wizard show any problems or warnings? Were those fixed?

when I moved all the forms perhaps the problem is one form, or one component that does something it shouldn't. Try moving only half the forms, or only 1/4 of the forms etc until you can isolate which form fails

I upgrade it with the method that Jimi says (official method). I'm gonna try to do Panagiotis' suggestion first.

Your screenshot show3s a link to display the call stack. Did you do that? That's diagnostic information that is intended to help you diagnose the issue. If you want us to help you diagnose it, show us that information. It may or may not be useful but we won't know until we see it.

ah yeah, forget to add that

Some types, like MemoryStream, are not marked as Serializable in .NET 8, which can break compatibility with components that expect serialization.
Inspect the error form for code that may implicitly require serialization, especially if they use non-serializable types like MemoryStream. Convert the MemoryStream to a byte array (using MemoryStream.ToArray() or MemoryStream.GetBuffer()). Then, pass this byte array instead of the MemoryStream itself.
